# Kill the decorating tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Sparked by recent [chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3665378#3665378).

There are [11 questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decorating?sort=newest) marked with the decorating tag, but I don't believe they add much value to the question.  The tag is also problematic since it leads to confusion about choosing decorations perhaps being on-topic.

My inclination is to go through and remove the tag from those questions, but I wanted to see if there's a compelling reason to keep it around.

Update:  Deed is done - sorry about the home page.

Comment: It's not too bad :)

Answer (score 7):

If you think the tag can be safely removed from those questions then go ahead.

I agree that it seems to be a problematical tag for the reasons you've given.

We ought to keep an eye out for it's reappearance and if necessary request a tag blacklist. However, that's the last resort.

Comment: Can a mere mortal delete a tag, does it require moderator attention, or does it just die on it's own if left abandoned? Actually the last option sounds sort of sad, poor little tag :(

Comment: @Tester101 - Even moderators can't kill tags - we can only merge them. If a tag is removed from all questions then it gets automatically removed from the system after 24 hours. From then on it won't be suggested in the tags box. However, if you have sufficient reputation you can recreate it - but this will be a **new** tag that happens to have the same name.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, go ahead and remove the tag.